# Homestead global installation unable to connect to the second website

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, homestead

I have Homestead/Vagrant installed globally, that references two sites. I am successfully able to connect to the database of the first site.

When attempting to `php artisan migrate:refresh --seed` on the second website (audit), I get a connection refused error.

I can manually access the database, using the credentials I provide in the .env file, so I'm unsure what the problem is.

**Current setup:**

.env

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=33060
DB_DATABASE=audit
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

./homestead/Homestead.yml:

```
folders:
    - map: ~/compare
      to: /home/vagrant/compare
    - map: ~/audit
      to: /home/vagrant/audit

sites:
    - map: compare.app
      to: /home/vagrant/compare/public
    - map: audit.app
      to: /home/vagrant/audit/public

databases:
    - compare
    - audit
```

/etc/hosts:

```
192.168.10.10   compare.app

192.168.10.10   audit.app
```

Why can't I connect to the database?

Comment: Please confirm `DB_PORT=33060` is not a typo, and `DB_DATABASE` is `compare` and `audit` respectively.

Comment: `DB_PORT` shows:     `22 (guest) => 2204 (host),
 27017 (guest) => 27017 (host),
  3306 (guest) => 2202 (host),
   443 (guest) => 2201 (host),
  5432 (guest) => 2203 (host),
    80 (guest) => 2200 (host)`

Comment: Whether I use port 3306, or 33060 (as shown in Laravel docs) or 2202, I still can't connect.

Comment: I can connect in `Sequel Pro`, if I use `2202`, but I can't through the Laravel app for some reason.

Comment: Sorry,  I  was asking  about your .env file. Port 33060 is  exposed to the host,  whilst the guest should  use normal 3306.  You are running  artisan from the guest,  aren't you?